# AlertDialog.Builder solo cerrar si presiono OK

Tags: android

Tengo este dialogo y quiero que solo se cierre si presiono OK.
Ahora si presiono en cualquier parte de la pantalla (fuera del dialogo) se cierra y no ejecuta OK.

Gracias.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( ActivitySedeCarpeta.this );
                        alertDialog.setMessage( "El Proceso ha empezado en sus Entragas y/o Recogidas." )
                                .setTitle( "Proceso Empezado" )
                                .setIcon( R.drawable.informacion )
                                .setPositiveButton( "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        sw_entrega = "1";
                                        onBackPressed();
                                    }
                                } );
                        alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Configuralo como `setCancelable(false)`

Answer (score 2):

Agrega la propiedad [.setCancelable(false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder#setCancelable(boolean)), para determinar que el diálogo no se pueda cancelar:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( ActivitySedeCarpeta.this );
                        alertDialog.setMessage( "El Proceso ha empezado en sus Entragas y/o Recogidas." )
                                .setTitle( "Proceso Empezado" )
                                .setIcon( R.drawable.informacion )
                                .setCancelable(false) //* Evita se cierre el Diálogo
                                .setPositiveButton( "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        sw_entrega = "1";
                                        onBackPressed();
                                    }
                                } );
                        alertDialog.show();
```